# Is there a way to write to multiple files in the same folder?

Tags: c#

I have two folders with the same files in them. I'm trying to read from the files in one folder, "do stuff" and write to the files with the same name in the other.

I have tried File.WriteAllText but it gives me an exception unhandled error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\'.'

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory);
foreach (string file in files)
{
   StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
     // do stuff
      newFile.Append(x);
   }
   File.WriteAllText(targetDirectory, newFile.ToString());
}
```

I want to make changes to all the files in the directory.

Comment: It helps when you tell us what exception you get.

Comment: `newFile.Append(x);` what is `x` ? What is your error message ?

Comment: There is nothing like write to all files at once. You have to write to them individually.

Comment: you should not write to a target**directory** but to a file!

Comment: You probably can't write text to a *directory*.

Comment: strip `file` of it's directory so that only the name remains, then use `Path.Combine(directory, fileName)` to make a new filename with proper path

Comment: @BrootsWaymb System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\'.'

Comment: next time, please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56775861/edit) to add content

Comment: if one of the answers has helped you to solve your problem, you could consider to mark the answer as accepted as [described in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten to include the filename of the target file.  Change the last part to:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(file);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(targetDirectory, fi.Name), newFile.ToString());
```

This assumes that newFile.ToString() is actually what you want *inside* the target file :-)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [James answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56775966/1439998), adding a check to see if the directory exists may solve your issue.

```
var fi = new FileInfo(file);
if(!fi.Directory.Exists)
     fi.Directory.Create()
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(targetDirectory, fi.Name), newFile.ToString());
```